# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. Hiding buttons according to CanCan permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin and CanCan working together. I already set the administrator and customer permissions.

Now I want to hide the New, Edit and Delete buttons according to the permissions set by CanCan but the following line gives me errors...

```
config.clear_action_items! :if => proc{can? (:destroy, Shipment)}
```

This one too

```
:if => proc{ can?(:destroy, Shipment)}, actions :all, :except => [:new, :create, :update, :edit, :destroy]
```

Comment: I believe that `current_user` must be available in order to check the abilities that way. I doubt it is available in any of configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I use this monkey patch to check permissions before displaying buttons

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class Resource
    module ActionItems

      # Adds the default action items to each resource
      def add_default_action_items
        # New Link on all actions except :new and :show
        add_action_item :except => [:new] do
          if controller.action_methods.include?('new') and can? :create, active_admin_config.resource_class
            link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.new_model', :model => ''), new_resource_path,
             :class => "new-link"
            )
          end
        end

        # Edit link on show
        add_action_item :only => :show do
          if controller.action_methods.include?('edit') and can? :update, active_admin_config.resource_class

             link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.edit_model', :model => ''), edit_resource_path(resource),
             :class => "edit-link"
            )


          end
        end

        # Destroy link on show
        add_action_item :only => :show do
          if controller.action_methods.include?("destroy") and can? :destroy, active_admin_config.resource_class

             link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.delete_model', :model => ''),
              resource_path(resource),
               :class => "delete-link" ,
              :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation')})

          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```